# Setting an alias for copying the current path from shell to clipboard fails

Tags: zsh, alias, xclip

I have added the following alias to my .zshrc:

```
alias pwdc="echo -n $PWD | xclip -selection clipboard"
```

it seems the present working directory is not getting updated, when I move to a different directory. I have tried this too:

```
alias pwdc="echo -n `pwd` | xclip -selection clipboard"
```

Can somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong?
any suggestion will be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in double quotes are expanded immediately, so you need to single quote the command (or at least the part with the variable):

```
$ alias cc='echo "$PWD"'
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ cc
/tmp/tmp.9OuF0ZAE1b
```

In any case, [using a function instead](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080) avoids such issues.